# How to abort Winsock connection after x time

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently developing my own `TeamSpeak3Bot`. For the connection part I'm using Microsoft's `Winsock` library.

Connection gets established like the following:

```
// Initialize Winsock
WSAData winSockData;
WORD dllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
long iResult = WSAStartup(dllVersion, &winSockData);
if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
    return;

addrinfo* serverAddress = nullptr;
addrinfo* ptr = nullptr, hints;
ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "10011", &hints, &serverAddress);
if (iResult != 0)
    return;

// Create communication socket
SOCKET connectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, /*IPPROTO_TCP*/0);
if (connectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    return;

// Establish connection to server
iResult = connect(connectSocket, serverAddress->ai_addr (int)serverAddress->ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    return;

// server address info not needed anymore
freeaddrinfo(serverAddress);
```

Since Winsock's `send()` and `recv()` function wait for the according send/receive action to be done first, the main thread gets paused during this time.

How to appropriately check for received input on `recv()`?, and how to abort `recv()` after a specific amount of time (in milliseconds) has passed?

Note: *I also need the ability to throw an class specific exception if, either `send()` or `recv()`, has timed out!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use non-blocking sockets and then you can poll.

You can set the socket to be non blocking by doing:

```
ULONG mode = 1;
int res = ioctlsocket(socket, FIONBIO, &mode);
```

This means that calls to recv return immediately if there's nothing there and return a `WSAGetLastError()` of `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: Using `ioctlsocket()` did it for me, thx. After executing a send/recv function I now check for `SOCKET_ERROR` and `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` first, if at least one of both is given, I throw an exception and loop over again till a specified time has been exceeded. Is this approach reasonable?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `select()` to wait for input to become available.  That lets you specify a timeout.  When `select()` tells you that input is available on the socket, you then use `recv()` to read it.